# event handler is not getting triggered inside polymer ready:function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am creating a custom Polymer component and I have following code inside ready function:

```
 ready: function() {
    this.width = 400;
    this.height = 400;
    var gif = new GIF({
            workers: 2,
            quality: 10,
            width: this.width,
            height: this.height
        });
        gif.on('finished', function (blob) {
            console.log('finished');
        });}
```

Now after I call `gif.render();`,  `'finished'` event should be triggered. It is working fine when I developed an HTML, JavaScript application, but it is not getting triggered here inside `ready:function(){}`

So is this because of polymer behavior or i am doing any thing wrong?

I am trying to use [gif.js](https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js) library.

Comment: Maybe you need to add it to the DOM first? Just a wild guess, I don't know gif.js

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make gif a property. Because your gif object will be gone after the ready function finishes

after you add the property "gif" change "var gif =" to "this.gif = "